# apache httpd.conf - spaces in file/path names

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, spaces

I have lines in Apache httpd.conf like:

```
AliasMatch ^/cart/images/(.*)  "/long/path/to/images/but containing
embedded spaces/$1"
```

This no longer works.

How do I specify the embedded spaces if surrounding quotes no longer work?

Comment: I've searched Apache documentation - no mention

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly now works! Been trying to fix this for nearly 2 weeks.